# How to generate WTForm(s) based on SQLAlchemy models?

Tags: python, forms, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm tied to [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com) and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and I would like to save some typing.

How I can examine SQLA models schema (I use declarative models), and use things like `nullable=False`, `Unicode(50)`, to generate form fields with basic validators set-up (Required if nullable is false, Length if field is 'varchar' with max value etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this: [WTAlchemy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WTAlchemy) maybe will be useful for someone